# Swift - register and re-register push notifications

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

Im trying to find a way to de-authorise users for push notifications when they log out from an app Ive found this function `UIApplication.shared.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()` which aparently works however I never see notifications being disabled, I also read in the documentation that it should not be used often or something to that effect, I basically want to have a toggle button in my app where the user clicks it one way and gets the standard enable notifications popup and another way to disable notifications on the fly, Im not a native swift developer so any pointers welcome

Also is it possible to attach a callback to this to know if it executes successfully, Im trying the following but get the error `Argument passed to call that takes no arguments`

```
     UIApplication.shared.unregisterForRemoteNotifications() { (result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            call.error("Error", error)
        } else if let result = result {
            call.success([
                "deregister": true
            ])
        }
    }
```

Edit: I found this which says its not possible to toggle on and off [Change push notifications programmatically in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33517864/change-push-notifications-programmatically-in-swift)

With that in mind does this mean that the standard for devices is that:
1) when a user log out of their account they can still receive notifications.
2) When a user creates a new account on the same app it uses the same token and so receives notifications from the old account ?
3) when a user sells their phone and another guy/gal downloads the same app that they will receive notifications from that other users account (in terms of 3rd party push service one signal, aparently you dont need to refresh the player id)

Comment: 1: yes, 2: yes, 3: yes. The best solution is to track this server side, if the user wants to receive push or not. About #3, it's highly unlikely that the buyer will receive notifications from the previous owner, assuming the device will be reset completely before selling. Also its good practice to register for push on every app- launch and send the returned push token to your api.